# div image does not want to download

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, html2canvas

im having trouble downloading div image the reason why i want to download the image is so the user can upload it and save it to database. is their an easier way to save an image to database without going around downloading an image and uploading? the code below allows downloading without allowTaint once i make it true it will not allow me to download image is their a way to allowTaint and still save the image to database please help. allowTaint makes it possible for uploaded images inside the div to be visible

```js
$(function() { 

 
var element = $("#firstshirt"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable
 
    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
    allowTaint: true,
            logging: true,
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

 $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "<?php echo $confirm_coded ?>").attr("href", newData);
 });

});
```

Comment: If you can't export the resulting canvas with `allowTaint` set  to true, it means that somewhere in your *snapped* document, you've got a media (usually an image) that comes from an external domain, and not served with the proper cross-origin headers.

Comment: You've got different options : The easiest one and only cross-browser is to host yourself all your media. html2canvas will then be able to draw your html and your image without tainting the canvas. Option 2 is to request all your media with the `crossOrigin` attribute set to `anonymous`, this option will work in newest browsers (IE11+) and will require you to have access to the other server so it sends the proper request origin headers. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).